# Better time complexity for following task

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I was solving following problem today (unfortunately I didnt achieve required better time complexity).

Given a list of student test scores, find the best average grade. Each student may have more than one test score in the list, and the best average grade is the average of all test scores for that student.
Complete the bestAverageGrade function in the editor below.
It has one parameter, scores, which is an array of student test scores.  Each element in the array is a two-element array of the form [student name, test score] e.g. [ "Bobby", "87"].
More points will be awarded for solutions that can handle larger inputs within a set period of time i.e. code with a faster run-time complexity.

Input Format

The input parameter scores is an array of arrays, where each sub-array contains two strings: the student name followed by a test score as a string. You must also include the number of entries and the size of each entry (this will always be 2). See below for specific examples. Test scores may be positive or negative integers.

Output Format

Your function must return a single integer representing the best average grade.  If you end up with an average grade that is not an integer, you should use a floor function to return the largest integer less than or equal to the average.

Return 0 for an empty input.

Sample Input 0

```
[ [ "Bobby", "87" ],
  [ "Charles", "100" ],
  [ "Eric", "64" ],
  [ "Charles", "22" ] ]
```

entered as

4
2
Bobby 87
Charles 100
Eric 64
Charles 22

Sample Output 0
87

and here is me bestAverageGrade method:

```
def bestAverageGrade(scores):
    list_of_students = set([x[0] for x in scores])
    averages = []
    for student in list_of_students:
        results = [float(x[1]) for x in scores if x[0] == student]
        averages.append(sum(results_of_student)/len(results))
    return math.floor(max(averages))
```

How could I achieve better time complexity? I know that now list of lists is iterated two times.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well you iterate over the list for each student, which makes it a harder problem.

Comment: Use a running average and iterate over the list just once.

Comment: how to iterate just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over the list several times: one time for each student. If there are multiple students, then the number of loops can be rather large, so the time complexity can be - worst case - *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

We can use an approach where we for instance using a dictionary. We can define a dictionary `grades` that maps every student name on a 2-tuple (a numerator and denominator). In that case the code looks like:

## Vanilla Python

```
def bestAverageGrade(scores):
    grades = {}
    for student, grade in scores:
        grade = float(grade)
        current = grades.get(student)
        if current is None:
            grades[student] = grade, 1
        else:
            num, denom = current
            grades[student] = num + grade, denom + 1
    return math.floor(max(num/denom for num, denom in grades.values()))
```

## Pandas

We can also boost performance by using Pandas. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

def bestAverageGrade(scores):
    df = pd.DataFrame([[name, float(score)] for name, score in scores],
                      columns=['student', 'score'])
    return math.floor(df.groupby('student')['score'].mean().max())
```

So here we first group by students and take the mean as aggregate for the `'score'` column. Then we take the maximum over all these students.

Comment: @walkerous: what do you think the first section does?

Comment: I was pretty much giving the same answer using vanilla python, but you beat me to it. Nice one!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It should be done by vanilla python.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Javascript.**

```
function bestAverageGrade(scores) {
          if(!Array.isArray(scores) || scores.length === 0) return 0;
          let duplicateFrequency = {};
          let sumFrequency = {};
          scores.forEach(item =>  {
            duplicateFrequency[item[0]] = duplicateFrequency[item[0]] ? duplicateFrequency[item[0]]+1 : 1;
         sumFrequency[item[0]] = sumFrequency[item[0]] ? sumFrequency[item[0]]+Number(item[1]) : Number(item[1]);
    })
      for( let props in duplicateFrequency) {
        sumFrequency[props] = Math.floor(sumFrequency[props] / duplicateFrequency[props])
      }

     return Math.max(...Object.values(sumFrequency))
    }
```

**Time Complexity here is O(n)**

**Approach:** Here we are using two hashMaps one for storing the duplicates the other for storing the total marks for each student.

Then we are just reflecting over one of the hashMaps and dividing the total sum with the duplicates. Flooring the result to avoid decimals.

Finally, just use Math.max to get the maximum value.